# Using "GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP)" and... in C language

Tags: c, winapi

I wanna use Arrow keys in C language with the command `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP)` (and VK_LEFT , ... ).

But I don't know how can I use **switch** command with these cases **VK_UP, VK_LEFT... ** Is here anyone who can help me?

Comment: It doesn't make sense so use switch/case here. [`GetAsyncKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) doesn't tell you which key has been pressed, but it rathers tell you if some key is being held down or not.

Comment: Example: `if ((GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL)&0x8000) == 0) // ctrl not pressed`

Comment: @paul that's the wrong test, key is down if and only if function returns negative

Comment: It is correct, there are two ways to do it.  That its return value type is SHORT is quite unusual, but certainly intentional.

Comment: Anyhoo, GetAsyncKeyState() is pretty awkward.  Check if your CRT provides the conio.h header file so you can use `_getch()`.  Or consider ReadConsoleInput().  Now you can use switch/case as you intended.

Comment: @HansPassant +1 `_kbhit()` togtether with `_getch()` should do all tricks required for simple programs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the documentation says "_If the most significant bit is set, the key is down_". The return type is SHORT, which is typedef'd to `short` so your test works. However, should at sometime it be defined as `unsigned short`, then your test will not work. So the test must either test for the high bit, or the result of the function is first explicitly cast to `(short)` to eliminate any unsignedness and then checked to be negative.

Answer (score 1):

`GetAsyncKeyState` doesn't return a virtual key code. It returns the state of the key, down or up. It doesn't take an array as a param either.

But you can implement this .

pseudocode:

```
 bool Active = true; 
   char lastKeyPress; 
   while(Active) { 
     for(int i=8; i<190; i++){ 
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(i)) 
           checkKey(i) 
     } 
   } 
   void checkKey(int key) { 
     swtch(key) 
     { 
       case VK_F1: 
        case VK_F2: 
         //and so on.. 
     } 
  }
```

And for more information you may surf here [Keylogging](https://bothack.wordpress.com/2007/12/12/keylogging-fun-for-cc-beginners/)  and [GetKeyboardState function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardstate).